# Auto-generating EF "where" clause based on DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to autogenerate the parameter to IQueryable.Where so I can select entities from my entity framework code first data context without writing and wiring up a lot of tedious mapping code.

My project contains a bunch of DTOs that look like:-

```
class FooDto
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And a bunch of entities that look like:-

```
class Foo
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }

  // Some other properties here.
}
```

The DTO contains the fields necessary to identify some subset of entities in my database. I use the DTOs to query an IQueryable of entities:-

```
var result = queryable.Where(
  x => x.SomeProperty == dto.SomeProperty
    && x.SomeOtherProperty == dto.SomeOtherProperty)
```

The actual properties vary, but the queries are always of the shape **"Where all of the properties on the entity match all of the matching properties on the DTO"**. There's no more complicated query object functionality going around.

There are many dozens of DTOs and entities. Creating/maintaining and wiring up all of these predicates is a challenging architectural issue. We're currently using the strategy pattern:-

```
public class FooDtoSelectStrategy : ISelectStrategy<FooDto, FooEntity>
{
  public Func<FooEntity, bool> GetPredicate(FooDto dto)
  {
    return x => x.SomeProperty == dto.SomeProperty
             && x.SomeOtherProperty == dto.SomeOtherProperty;
  }
}
```

Along with a pile of ninject bindings, but we've got some few dozens of these already and we're looking at hundreds more as our domain expands.

We had a similar challenge mapping values from the entity to the DTO which we resolved using AutoMapper.

**Can automapper (or a similar tool) create these predicates and allow us to implement a single `GenericPredicateProvider<TDto, TEntity>`?**

Comment: AutoMapper doesn't generate anything, all it does is create instances (maybe) and copy values.

Comment: Mm. AutoMapper doesn't on its own solve my problem, but CreateMapExpression is tantalisingly close.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is actually called the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).  So you've basically re-engineered the wheel, coming up with a slightly different wheel that is basically the same thing.

You could use something like T4 templates to auto-generate these Predicate providers, but it seems kind of silly that you are querying an object for the identical object.  You already have the object, so why are you querying all the fields for the exact same thing?

Comment: I don't already have the object: I have a DTO that contains all the fields necessary to select a set of entities from my data context, and I need those entities.

I'm pretty sure the specification pattern doesn't apply here. I'm not testing whether an object satisfies a business rule. I'm building an expression tree that I can use as the parameter to IQueryable.Where.

Comment: @IainGalloway - That's precisely what the Specification pattern is for.  An example is LinqSpecs (which has been subsumed into the NetFX project, but the LinqSpecs codeplex site has enough info to let you understand how it works).

Comment: I'll check out the NETFx version of LinqSpecs, but the documentation on it seems pretty thin on the ground. I don't think the original addresses the architectural issues I'm having though. My issues are a) I have to create a lot of these simple queries, and b) I have to wire them up. LinqSpecs in particular doesn't address a) at all (except by giving me the option to write *more* queries and and/or/not them together), and it addresses b) by having the caller *new* up the query objects as it needs them, meaning I'd still need to apply the strategy pattern as I did originally.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:-**

Here's my prototype using AutoMapper's type mapping to handle the simple case. It'll need more work later if I want it to handle e.g. complex type mapping, but for now this is doing the job.

```
internal class AutoMapperSelectStrategy<TEntity, TIdentity> :
    IIdentitySelectStrategy<TEntity, TIdentity>
{
    private IMappingEngine mappingEngine;

    internal AutoMapperSelectStrategy(
        IMappingEngine<TEntity, TIdentity> mappingEngine)
    {
        this.mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
    }

    public Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> GetPredicateForIdentity(
        TIdentity identity)
    {
        var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));

        var identityScope = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
            Expression.Constant(
                new ExpressionScope<TIdentity>() { Value = identity }),
                typeof(ExpressionScope<TIdentity>).GetProperty("Value"));

        var equalityExpressions = this.MakeEqualityExpressions(
            identityScope, entityParameter);

        var aggregateEquality = equalityExpressions.Aggregate(
            (x, y) => Expression.AndAlso(x, y));

        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
            aggregateEquality, entityParameter);

        return predicate;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BinaryExpression> MakeEqualityExpressions(
        MemberExpression identityScope, ParameterExpression entityParameter)
    {
        var mapExpression =
            mappingEngine.CreateMapExpression<TIdentity, TEntity>();

        var body = mapExpression.Body as MemberInitExpression;
        var bindings = body.Bindings;

        foreach (var binding in bindings.OfType<MemberAssignment>())
        {
            var memberExpression = binding.Expression as MemberExpression;

            var left = Expression.Property(
                identityScope, memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo);
            var right = Expression.Property(
                entityParameter, binding.Member as PropertyInfo);

            var equalityExpression = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            yield return equalityExpression;
        }
    }

    private class ExpressionScope<TDto>
    {
        public TDto Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```